# Render HTML String Within A Webpage

Tags: javascript, html, django

I'm building a user dashboard in Django for a python based web service. This web service creates emails, and the HTML strings of these emails are saved in a file (and could theoretically also be saved in a db table). As part of the dashboard functionality I want to be able to preview the email, essentially rendering the html string of the email within the Django html view. Is it possible to do this? Will I need to work with a Javascript library to achieve this? Which one? Any help would be very appreciated!

**EDIT**

To clarify, the html string when put into a text editor is about 360+ lines. It has its own styling and it's own `<head>`, `<body>`, etcetera, tags. I want to display it like a webpage within a webpage, if that makes sense, so that it looks like a proper preview. I just have no idea how to do this, my experience hasn't really been with js or front end dev.

Comment: You can render it. What's exactly the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make the email html available like any other page and display it inside of an iframe.

be warned - email clients don't use the same rendering engines as browsers. its hell. (we use this - https://litmus.com)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing more but:

```
document.getElementById('IDofDisplayContainer').innerHTML = 'your mail HTML string';
```